# How do you copy certain bits from a variable in c to another variable?

Tags: c++, c

Say I have a long 64 bit integer that starts with these bits:

0100 0000 0110 1101 .... .... ....

And I want a specific integer to hold this value:

0b10000000110

Which, as you can see are bits 2 through 12 in the original number.

How can I do this with bitwise operations is this possible?

Comment: The language doesn't mandate any layout of "bits" in variable's values, so whatever you do will work for *that* architecture and *that* specific compiler. Change just operating system, the result could very well be completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
uint64_t input = <0100 0000 0110 1101 .... .... ....>
uint64_t mask = (uint64_t)0x7FF << 52;
uint64_t output = (input & mask) >> 52;
```

`0x7ff` is eleven bits: `11111111111`. Shift it left 52 bits to get it where you want, use it to mask the input value, and shift the return value back 52 bits.

Comment: I'm getting shift count too large when I try to shift 52 bits, don't know why

Comment: Is that a warning or an error? Does it give you the correct result at least?

Comment: it's a warning, but I dont feel I am getting the correct result unless somewhere else in my code I'm doing something incorrectly. I will debug some more

Comment: Edited. 0x7ff should be long. That fixes the warning at least.

Comment: Change to `uint64_t mask = (uint64_t)0x7FF << 52;`.  You have to promote the left-hand operand to the correct data type before shifting it. (The `L` suffix would be wrong if your system had 32-bit longs, for example).